# insert a chart object at a specific location

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have written a macro in excel to insert a chart.
The macro is run when a particular range of cells is selected.
It is:

```
Sub drawchart2()
'
' drawchart2 Macro
'

'
  Range("B24:C36").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Sheet'!$B$24:$C$36" _
        )
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementLeft 256.1797637795
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementTop -84.2696062992
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementLeft 54.7752755906
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Chart 6").IncrementTop -19.3820472441
End Sub
```

But this chart is inserted in the middle of the excel worksheet.I want to insert it onto the right top corner of the sheet.How do i Do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can position it to the top easily but the right is arbitrary because someone can resize the window or scroll.  Excel defaults position from upper left corner for this reason.  You can get the width of the screen and do a little math but I doubt that's what you really want.  Is there a set distance from the left edge or specific column you can position from horizontally?

Here is how to position from the top:

```
 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select

 With ActiveChart
    .ChartType = xlLineMarkers
    .SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$B$24:$C$36")
    .Parent.Top = 0
    .Parent.Left = 100
 End With
```